# How to add a fragment to a layout of a DialogFragment?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment, fragmenttransaction

I am having a custom `DialogFragment` which contains a layout, some UI elements, and a Fragment holder layout. What I need to do is inflate a Content fragment into the holder layout and provide a navigation inside that. On clicking a button inside the added fragment the view will navigate to another view. The fragment will be replaced by another one in the same holder i.e. the `contentFragment1` will show some data and on clicking a preview button there will replace `contentFragment1` with `contentFragment2`.
I read somewhere that you cannot replace a fragment hardcoded to the `xml` with another one.
So I am trying to add the `contentFragment1` to the `viewholder` from the `onActivityCreated()` of the dialog fragment. But I am getting an error that the resource pointed by `R.id.fragmentHolder` not found. What could be the possible reason?

Here is my code for the `DialogFragment`:

```
public class MyDialog extends DialogFragment {
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Dialog customDialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
    customDialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    customDialog.setContentView(R.layout.reports_dialog);
    return customDialog;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    android.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.myFragmentHolder, new ReportsListFragment());
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}
```

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent" >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="This is my header text view for the Dialog"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/myFragmentHolder"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/headerlayout" >

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: post R.layout.reports_dialog layout as well

Answer (score 5):

After trying a lot, I came to a conclusion that `onCreateDialog()` doesn't have a view, it just sets a view on calling `setView()`.

That is why on adding dynamic(framelayout tag) or static fragment(fragment tag) in the layout of the dialogfragment gives *no parent view* or *duplicate id* error.

To achieve the above, one should use `onCreateView` with a framelayout tag which can be inflated dynamically. Title and alert buttons are then added to the layout.

Comment: This is extremely helpful, thank you! Just implementing this method and returning the view did the trick for me.

Comment: Using getChildFragmentManager() instead of getFragmentManager() helped in this case.

Answer (score 4):

`R.id.myFragmentHolder` is inflated to the dialog's layout, and `getFragmentManager()` returns the manager for the activity, so it can't find the view.

With nested fragments in API level 17 you can use `getChildFragmentManager()`.

Comment: For API level < 17, `getChildFragmentManager()` is available in the support library. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/23640194/1617737 .

Answer (score 1):

Just be sure that the reports_dialog layout containts a layout whose id myFragmentHolder like this one

```
<FrameLayout
android:id="@+id/fragment_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for reference here, as Brandon mention the correct answer is to use the **getChildFragmentManager()**, keeping in mind, that android will also restore the state of fragments.

The correct code, to add your first fragment, is:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // if the saved instance isn't null, the fragment state will be restored by android
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.myFragmentHolder, new ReportsListFragment()).commit();
    }
}
```

after the view has been added. Later use replace if only one fragment should be shown at the same time.

I would also recommend to call **transaction.addToBackStack(null);** if the Android back button should be supported.

Answer (score 0):

id of fragment holder in layout is `fragmentHolder` and you are using `myFragmentHolder` in code try to replace this by:

```
 fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragmentHolder, new ReportsListFragment());
```

Comment: Oh. I am sorry. I have edited the xml to make it compact and accidentally renamed the id while copying the code to stackoverflow. The id points correctly in my code. But it is still showing the same error.