# getChildFragmentManager() and support libraries

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-nested-fragment

I am using the `getChildFragmentManager()` in an app that is compiling against API level 19, with the minimum SDK set to 14.

`getChildFragmentManager()` was introduced in API 17, so devices running at API levels 14, 15, or 16 will throw a `NoSuchMethodError` when the method is called.

I did look through all the other StackOverflow questions regarding this issue, but none of them seem to answer this question: is there any way to get the `getChildFragmentManager()` method to work on devices pre-API level 17? If so, how?

The method does not seem to be included in either the v4 or v13 support libraries. I have tried clean builds with both v4 and v13 support libraries, but that does not seem to solve the issue.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> is there any way to get the getChildFragmentManager() method to work on devices pre-API level 17? If so, how?

Use the backport of fragments from the Android Support package (`android-support-v4.jar`, `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`).

> The method does not seem to be included in either the v4 or v13 support libraries.

<strike>Yes, it is, on `FragmentActivity`, the `Activity` base class you need to use in order to use the fragments backport.</strike>

It is on the `Fragment` class from the backport, for managing child fragments of that fragment.

> I have tried clean builds with both v4 and v13 support libraries, but that does not seem to solve the issue.

Either you did not change to <strike>`FragmentActivity`</strike> the `Fragment` backport, or your support library JARs are old. [Here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ViewPager/Nested) demonstrating the use of <strike>`FragmentActivity`</strike> the `Fragment` backport and its `getChildFragmentManager()`.

Comment: [`getChildFragmentManager()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#getChildFragmentManager()) is on `Fragment`, not `FragmentActivity`

Answer (score 0):

You could try the SupportFragmentManager instead:

```
yourFragment = (YourFragment) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.playListFragment)
```