# App crash when using getMapAsync() in MapsView

Tags: java, android, google-maps-android-api-2

I have a mapsview and it works fine when using `getMap()` although it shows me a depricated warning. But when i change `getMap()` to `getMapAsync()` the app will crash.

Here's my code

```
public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMapAsync(this);

        mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(this);
        mMap.setOnInfoWindowCloseListener(this);
        mMap.setOnMarkerDragListener(this);

        mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
                markerPoints.add(latLng);
                MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();
                // Setting the position of the marker
                options.position(latLng);
            }
        });

        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {    
                //Getting the coordinates
                toLatitude = marker.getPosition().latitude;
                toLongitude = marker.getPosition().longitude;

                dest = new LatLng(toLatitude, toLongitude);
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(dest));

                return ((toLatitude == my_marker.getPosition().latitude) && (toLongitude == my_marker.getPosition().longitude));
            }
        });
    }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        setUpMap();
    }

    private void setUpMap() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Anda harus menyetujuinya agar dapat menikmati semua fitur yang ada", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            }
        }

        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        mMap.setTrafficEnabled(true);
        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .zoom(15)                   // Sets the zoom
                .target(new LatLng(-6.597629,106.79957))
                .tilt(40)                   // Sets the tilt of the camera to 30 degrees
                .build();                   // Creates a CameraPosition from the builder
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
    }
}
```

Here's the xml layout

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MapsActivity">

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

This is the manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

What's wrong with my code? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Got Logcat output?

Comment: I can't see the logcat because i try the app through installation of it's apk. Because i'm not running this in emulator, and my usb hardware is not functioning properly. So i can't run it in my device directly :(

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
SupportMapFragment mapFragment =  ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));

    if(mapFragment != null) {
       mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)
    }
```

and move code

```
mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(this);
    mMap.setOnInfoWindowCloseListener(this);
    mMap.setOnMarkerDragListener(this);

    mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
            markerPoints.add(latLng);
            MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();
            // Setting the position of the marker
            options.position(latLng);
        }
    });

    mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {    
            //Getting the coordinates
            toLatitude = marker.getPosition().latitude;
            toLongitude = marker.getPosition().longitude;

            dest = new LatLng(toLatitude, toLongitude);
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(dest));

            return ((toLatitude == my_marker.getPosition().latitude) && (toLongitude == my_marker.getPosition().longitude));
        }
    });
}
```

to setUpMap() method, i tried here. its working. check once please

Comment: Can not resolve method `getChildFragmentManager()` :(

Comment: import supporting library -----
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;

Comment: please check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23640066/getchildfragmentmanager-and-support-libraries

Comment: I have imported that library but it's not working. Still Can not resolve method `getChildFragmentManager()`

Comment: oh! getChildFragmentManager() is a method of a Fragment. As you are using AppCompatActivity, you can't access it.

Comment: Any solution for this case? Because i need AppCompatActivity for this mapsview

Comment: Please check my post above, i have updated my code. I hope you can help me to solve the problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the min sdk version? can you change it to 19 and check once

Answer (score 0):

First thing to notice is this method expects [OnMapReadyCallback](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/OnMapReadyCallback), As per the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment.html#public-methods). The major rules to be noted are,

- *This method must be called from the main thread.*
- *In the case where Google Play services is not installed on the user's device,    the callback will not be triggered until the user installs it.*
- *In the rare case where the GoogleMap is destroyed immediately after creation, the callback is not triggered.*

If these rules are not followed properly either you won't get proper result, or app may crash up. So I suggest you to use [OnMapReadyCallback](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/OnMapReadyCallback) for `getMapAsync` method.