# App crash when using getMapAsync() in MapsView - Android

Tags: java, android, google-maps-android-api-2

I have a mapsview and it works fine when using getMap() although it shows me a depricated warning. But when i change `getMap()` to `getMapAsync()` the app will crash.

Here's my code

```
public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener,
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    GoogleMap.OnMarkerDragListener,
    GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowCloseListener,
    LocationListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMapAsync(this);

        mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(this);
        mMap.setOnInfoWindowCloseListener(this);
        mMap.setOnMarkerDragListener(this);

        mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
                markerPoints.add(latLng);
                MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();
                // Setting the position of the marker
                options.position(latLng);
            }
        });

        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {    
                //Getting the coordinates
                toLatitude = marker.getPosition().latitude;
                toLongitude = marker.getPosition().longitude;

                dest = new LatLng(toLatitude, toLongitude);
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(dest));

                return ((toLatitude == my_marker.getPosition().latitude) && (toLongitude == my_marker.getPosition().longitude));
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        setUpMap();
    }

    private void setUpMap() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Anda harus menyetujuinya agar dapat menikmati semua fitur yang ada", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            }
        }

        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        mMap.setTrafficEnabled(true);
        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .zoom(15)                   // Sets the zoom
                .target(new LatLng(-6.597629,106.79957))
                .tilt(40)                   // Sets the tilt of the camera to 30 degrees
                .build();                   // Creates a CameraPosition from the builder
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
    }
}
```

Here's the xml layout

```
   <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

What's wrong with my code? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Please Post logcat

Comment: And the exception is?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [App crash when using getMapAsync() in MapsView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36193731/app-crash-when-using-getmapasync-in-mapsview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that **mMap** is the GoogleMap object here.What you are doing is using **mMap** before it gets initialized so it must be throwing **null pointer exception**.

> Make sure to use mMap object in onMapReady Callback.Hope it solves
>   your problem.So, in short all you need to do is place all your mMap
>   usages in onMap Ready callback

Answer (score 0):

At the moment of `getMapAsync` call the `onMapReady` is not done. Be sure that  `((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))` is not null or `onMapReady()` has finished with success.

Comment: I have change my code become like this `SupportMapFragment mapFragment =  ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));

    if(mapFragment != null) {
       mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)
    }`
But still crash :(