# Creating a DialogFragment - using onCreateDialog() or onCreateView()?

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I would like to create a home screen with a **login button**, which when clicked, opens a dialog box to enter a password and then either submit or cancelled.

I have read that there are two methods to do this in order to create a `DialogFragment`- using `onCreateDialog()` and `onCreateView()`.

What is the difference between these two options, and which one is used in which scenarios?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom Layout for DialogFragment OnCreateView vs. OnCreateDialog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13257038/custom-layout-for-dialogfragment-oncreateview-vs-oncreatedialog)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `onCreateDialog()` is for displaying Basic Dialog. This is the simplest way to display a dialog. While using this method you need to use the builder method of the inbuilt dialog like AlertDialog to build the dialog and listeners for positive and negative button and return a Dialog.

On the other hand `OnCreateView()` you can return a view to be used as a dialog. You can use your own layout to build a dialog UI. Your own button and listen for them. In simple words your own Custom Dialog.

Also Note: You can even set a view to your built in Dialog like AlerDialog in `onCreateDialog()` by calling setView() method. The `onCreateView()` is used to build your dialog from your own layout. Which version should you use is entirely upto you. I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you!! This is very helpful.

Comment: There are some problem with list performance depending on which method you use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41515730/dialogfragment-recyclerview-swap-animation-lags-depending-on-the-method-used-t